# Load Runner Windows Sockets lrs_save_param warning\not found

Tags: windows, sockets, loadrunner

I am working on Loadrunner winsocket protocol and trying to figure if there is an option in lrs_save_param or lrs_save_searched_string function to mark it as warning or not found if the received buffer is empty.

If there is no response, is it possible to mark that transaction as fail and continue the next iterations?

With the below code, if there is no response, the user fails and exits the test.

```
lrs_create_socket("socket9", "TCP", "RemoteHost={dpHostName}:8800",   LrsLastArg);
lrs_send("socket9", "buf5", LrsLastArg);
lrs_receive("socket9", "buf6", LrsLastArg);
lrs_save_searched_string("socket9", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "CorrelationParameter", "LB/BIN=AUTH, "RB/BIN=,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 1, 0, -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot escape errors: if **lrs_receive()** fails to receive the response or **lrs_save_searched_string()** doesn't find the searched string, your script will end with Error result. There is no such option in these functions to make them silence errors. However, you could force LoadRunner to ignore errors and continue script execution by using *Continue on error* mode. There are 2 ways of using it:

1. Tick *Continue on error* in the *Run-time Settings->General->Miscellaneous*.
2. Use **lr_continue_on_error()** function to ignore errors in a specific scope.

You could do something like that:

```
lrs_create_socket("socket9", "TCP", "RemoteHost={dpHostName}:8800",   LrsLastArg);
lrs_send("socket9", "buf5", LrsLastArg);

// start of code with possible failures
lr_continue_on_error(1);

if (lrs_receive("socket9", "buf6", LrsLastArg) != 0)
{
    lr_output_message("could not receive the response!");
}
if (lrs_save_searched_string("socket9", LRS_LAST_RECEIVED, "CorrelationParameter", 
    "LB/BIN=AUTH", "RB/BIN=,,,,,,,,,,,,,", 1, 0, -1) == LRS_SAVE_PARAM_ERR)
{
    lr_output_message("parameter not found!");
}
// end of code with possible failures
lr_continue_on_error(0);
```

Check *[LR directory]\include\lrs_err.h* for other error codes.